# Headless endless scroll selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib,requests,unidecode,lxml,pdb
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
class wait_for_more_than_n_elements_to_be_present(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, count):
        self.locator = locator
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            elements = EC._find_elements(driver, self.locator)
            return len(elements) > self.count
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

def return_html_code(url):
    print url #added in edit 1
    vdisplay =Xvfb()
    vdisplay.start()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)
    # initial wait for the tweets to load
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 240)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-item-id]")))
    # scroll down to the last tweet until there is no more tweets loaded
    while True:
        tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[data-item-id]")
        print len(tweets)  #added in edit 1
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tweets[-1])
        try:
            wait.until(wait_for_more_than_n_elements_to_be_present((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-item-id]"), number_of_tweets))
        except TimeoutException:
            break
     html_full_source=driver.page_source
     driver.close()
     vdisplay.stop()
     html_full=return_html_code(url)
```

Output:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=Error%20Check&src=typd&lang=en
20
39
56
74
```

I have the above code for endlessly scrolling a page in endless mode. But somehow it seems to stops before.
References-https://stackoverflow.com/a/31058403/3646408

Edit 1:

```
$ phantomjs --version
2.1.1
```

On runnning @alexce code it showed different output in 2 runs, the date check makes it clear that there are more tweets:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=Error%20Check&src=typd&lang=en
20
40
59
76
95
114
133
152
171
191
211
231
249
267
Date of most old tweet: 12 Jan 2016


https://twitter.com/search?q=Error%20Check&src=typd&lang=en
20
40
59
76
95
114
133
152
171
191
211
231
249
267
287
303
317
337
356
373
388
400
418
437
457
476
492
Date of most old tweet: 8 Jan 2016
```

Edit2:

On runnning updated version of  @alexce's code. It showed the below error after ~7000 tweets.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "twitter_script.py", line 82, in <module>
        search_twitter('Alcoholics Anonymous')
      File "twitter_script.py", line 76, in search_twitter
        db_name=write_data_to_db(*get_twitter_data(query))
      File "twitter_script.py", line 24, in get_twitter_data
        html_full=return_html_code(url)
      File "c:\Users\sony\Desktop\social_network_extract_old\social_network_extract\scrollDownHtmlCode.py", line 48, in return_html_code
        html_full_source=driver.page_source
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 464, in page_source
        return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
        response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
        return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
        resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open
        r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 453, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
        line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
        data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
    socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Edit 3:
Trying the same code for different url.

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=Alcoholics%20Anonymous%20Drunk%20since%3A2006-03-24%20until%3A2006-04-23&src=typd&lang=en
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_script.py", line 64, in <module>
    search_twitter('Alcoholics Anonymous Drunk')
  File "twitter_script.py", line 58, in search_twitter
    db_name=write_data_to_db(*get_twitter_data(query))
  File "twitter_script.py", line 31, in get_twitter_data
    html_full=return_html_code(url)
  File "c:\Users\sony\Desktop\social_network_extract_old\social_network_extract\scrollDownHtmlCode.py", line 30, in return_html_code
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-item-id]")))
  File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Edit 4:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-123:~/social_network_extract_proxy$ cat error.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_script.py", line 70, in <module>
    search_twitter('alcoholics anonymous')
  File "twitter_script.py", line 64, in search_twitter
    db_name=write_data_to_db(*get_twitter_data(query))
  File "twitter_script.py", line 37, in get_twitter_data
    html_full=return_html_code(url)
  File "/home/ubuntu/social_network_extract_proxy/firefox_driver_code.py", line 35, in return_html_code
    driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpvFoPrE If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Got the above error after a while.

Comment: Could you provide the twitter page you are working with and print out the `number_of_tweets` on each iteration - how many do you see loaded before it stops? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I added these in question now, please check now. Thanks, for the suggestion.

Comment: @alecxe url: `https://twitter.com/search?q=Error%20Check&src=typd&lang=en`
and tweets retrived: `74`

Comment: @alecxe @Abhishek - Did this work in the end, using endless scrolling? Were you able to copy/save the HTML code of the 'endlessly' long page using `driver.page_source`? I had some of the problems you described above, which were actually artefacts of how the Twitter advanced search works. I'd be interested in an update of your final solution and the results! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a set of things that made it work for me in headless mode:

- switch to `PhantomJS`
- [pretend to be a different browser by setting a custom User-Agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18433453/771848)
- before scrolling into view of the last tweet, scroll to the top of the page (several times to increase reliability)

The code:

```
import time

def return_html_code(url):
    dcap = dict(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get(url)

    # initial wait for the tweets to load
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-item-id]")))
    # scroll down to the last tweet until there is no more tweets loaded
    while True:
        tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li[data-item-id]")
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        print(number_of_tweets)

        # move to the top and then to the bottom 5 times in a row
        for _ in range(5):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tweets[-1])
            time.sleep(0.5)

        try:
            wait.until(wait_for_more_than_n_elements_to_be_present((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-item-id]"), number_of_tweets))
        except TimeoutException:
            break
```

Comment: shows me this error -`dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
NameError: global name 'DesiredCapabilities' is not defined `

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia interesting, works for me, are you using `PhantomJS` 2.0.0 and selenium 2.49?

Comment: I am using `PhantomJS 1.9.8` and `selenium 2.49`

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia could you please make a quick try with phantomjs 2? Thanks.

Comment: Did that, please check my Edit 1. Does it run endlessly for you? Seems the problem maybe somewhere else.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia yeah, interesting, I've got progress, see the updated answer. For now, it got me to 2000 tweets and still running. Hope it works for u too.

Comment: Thanks for the change! It seems to working fine now. I am just checking it to be sure. :)

Comment: Please check edit 2, for an error incurred. Seems to be linked to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia according to the traceback, the problem appeared when the page source was being retrieved, which, according to the code, happens after the loop. Is it consistent, do you always see this error? Also, two things to try - again with firefox with a virtual display and get the page source via `source = driver.executeScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML")`. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia yes, but, if I open this URL (https://twitter.com/search?q=Alcoholics%20Anonymous%20Drunk%20since%3A2011-01-24%20until%3A2011-02-23&src=typd&lang=en) in Chrome, I don't get any tweets loaded on scroll, and, when I run the code I've posted against this URL, I don't get the `TimeoutException` since it is handled by the try/except - I only get the `11` printed which is a number of tweets on this page - looks correct. Hope we are going to eventually solve it :) We are getting closer, step by step.

Comment: Try this : `https://twitter.com/search?q=Alcoholics%20Anonymous%20Drunk%20since%3A2006-03-24%20until%3A2006-04-23&src=typd&lang=en` please.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia no results if I follow this link. Assuming you meant https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=Alcoholics%20Anonymous%20Drunk&since=2006-03-2%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B4&until=2006-04-23&src=typd - it works for me, it is scrolling..

Comment: @alexce Your link doesn't seem correct. It displays all results irrespective of date. I am using the url generated from https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en. If you check for a page that shows no tweets, it gives the error as in Edit 3.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia thanks, just tried with the https://twitter.com/search?q=Alcoholics%20Anonymous%20Drunk%20%20since%3A2006-03-24&src=typd&lang=en. Works for me. Hope the link is correct.

Comment: Try with a link that doesn't give any results. Like: https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=stupid%20weird%20whatever%20Alcoholics%20Anonymous&src=typd

Comment: I am still getting the error in Edit 3. Though, it works with firefox. I tried your previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29463650/3646408 which doesn't help in this case. I can't contemplate the reason though, it works sometimes and doesn't other times.

Comment: Please Edit 4. It seems using proxies resolves the issue in Edit 3. Thanks for the help!