# How to scroll a page to the end

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

I have tried to do this:

```
driver_1.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

but it does nothing, so I made a loop to scroll the page by steps:

```
initial_value = 0
end = 300000
for i in xrange(1000,end,1000):
    driver_1.execute_script("window.scrollTo(" + str(initial_value) + ', ' +  str(i) + ")")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    initial_value = i
    print 'scrolling >>>>'
```

It kinda works, but I don't know how long is a a given page, so I have to put a  big number as the max height, that gives me two problems. First is that even a big number couldn't be large enought to scroll some pages and second one is that if the page is shorter than that limit a loss quite a lot time waiting for the script to finish when is doing nothing

Answer (score 2):

You need something to rely on, some indicator for you to stop scrolling. Here is an example use case when we would stop scrolling if more than N particular elements are already loaded:

- [Slow scrolling down the page using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942041/slow-scrolling-down-the-page-using-selenium)

Similar use case:

- [Headless endless scroll selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942103/headless-endless-scroll-selenium)

FYI, you may have noticed an other way to scroll to bottom - scrolling into view of a `footer`:

```
footer = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("footer")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer)
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll the page to the end, you could simply send the END key:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=selenium")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.END)
```

You could also scroll the full height :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=selenium")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found another solution that worked perfectly for me. [Check this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31058403/4288412) 
    Also this implementation:
    `driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.END)` does not work for pages that that use infinite scrolling design.

Comment: Rather than direct to someone else's answer, either provide the relevant components of the code here, or mark this question as a duplicate.