# Python: web scraping pages with js

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape LinkedIn using selenium.
Here's a page for example:
https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?firstName=mark

I can see in the html that the search results are in the:

`<div id='results-col'> ... </div>`

but when I try to access this tag using Beautifulsoup:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PATH)
browser.get(url)
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
results_col =  bs_obj.find("div", {"id": "results-col"})
```

I get nothing(results_col=None).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a sleep after the browser.get for the js to load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wait for the desired element](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to be present and only then get the page source:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...
browser.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "results-col")))

bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I tried your code but I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File X, line 142, in <module>
    print(get_link_to_profile(search_url))
  File X, line 121, in get_link_to_profile
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "results-col")))
  File "C:\Users\sergeyy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen

Comment: @BobSacamano that could mean different things, but you don't have this element on the page opened with PhantomJS. Take a screenshot with `take_screenshot()` method after loading the page and see what is actually opened. You might need to start `PhantomJS` with some arguments to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463603/phantomjs-returning-empty-web-page-python-selenium.

Comment: @BobSacamano or, you may need to tweak the user agent to pretend to be a different browser: https://coderwall.com/p/9jgaeq/set-phantomjs-user-agent-string.