# Selenium PhantomJS and Chrome drivers returning a blank page on a specific URL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I am running selenium/chrome in a docker container. Hence I used `webdriver.Remote`

Below is my code.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.get("https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/everything/browse/entertaining-at-home/cheese-board-selections?pageNumber=1")
print(driver.page_source)
```

My output is as below.

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

The code works with any other URL but not with the above one. I tried using PhantomJS as well but no luck.

I have seen [PhantomJS returning empty web page (python, Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463603/phantomjs-returning-empty-web-page-python-selenium?rq=1) but I do not know how to add the `service_args` to `webdriver.Remote`

Comment: I Got a blank page the first time I tried to load that page in my browser, it worked the second time though.  I would suggest it's a bug with the site

Comment: What output did you get? I am not getting anything at all. I tried many times using different proxies too.

Comment: I got `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. I've seen stuff like this before with a misconfigured nginx server that couldn't route traffic properly.